# Flutter align text on clickable Widget/button on the left

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, text-alignment

I am new to flutter so pls no disrespect. I don't know how to align my text in a clickable Widget/button on the left. I tried Text('', Textalign: textalign.left), but it didn't work You can see my code and an image of how it looks like now.

```
body: Container(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: [
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: ElevatedButton(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                primary: greyColor, minimumSize: Size(300, 60)),
            child:
                Text('Voreinstellung Parkplatz', textAlign: TextAlign.left),
            onPressed: () => tuNix(),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: ElevatedButton(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                primary: greyColor, minimumSize: Size(300, 60)),
            child: Text('Fixdesk auswählen', textAlign: TextAlign.left),
            onPressed: () => tuNix(),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

[image: how it looks]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```dart
child: ElevatedButton(
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft, //this
      primary: Colors.grey,
```

```dart
body: Container(
  child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    children: [
      Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: ElevatedButton(
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              primary: Colors.grey,
              minimumSize: Size(300, 60)),
          child:
              Text('Voreinstellung Parkplatz', textAlign: TextAlign.left),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: ElevatedButton(
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              primary: Colors.grey,
              minimumSize: Size(300, 60)),
          child: Text('Fixdesk auswählen', textAlign: TextAlign.left),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your Text widget inside Alignment.

```
Align(
  alignment:Alignment.centerLeft,
  child: Text('Voreinstellung Parkplatz',
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
  ),
),
```

See your widgets here
https://dartpad.dev/?id=e75b493dae1287757c5e1d77a0dc73f1